# javascript add object dynamically

Tags: javascript, object

I have this code where I added two Reviews (with the ID and NAME):

```
var data =  {
        SKU: 'CS4',
        Name: 'Dell Laptop Inspiron 41',
        Quantity: 1,
        ItemPrice: 121,
        "Reviews" : [
        {
            "ID": 2551,
            "Name": 'john',
        },
        {
            "ID": 255551,
            "Name": 'j5ohn',

        }
    };
```

[image]
How can I add them dynamically (i will get the reviews data from other sites using ajax) ?

I tried these code but I don't know why its not working and I am totally lost.

```
var data =  [{
        SKU: 'CS4',
        Name: 'Dell Laptop Inspiron 41',
        Quantity: 1,
        ItemPrice: 121,

    }];

var total_reviews = 5;

for (i=1; i<=total_reviews; i++) {

     Object.assign(data.Reviews, { "ID": data.from.other.sites.ID, "Name": data.from.other.sites.NAME });

}
```

Can you please give me advise which part I am missing ? or can you give me hints or codes for me to start?

Comment: If your "data" is an array you can't directly access the "Reviews" by doing data.Reviews. You will have to iterate through the data array and then assign a value to Reviews property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example output, the `Reviews` property of the object is an array of objects. This simple code should help you do that:

```js
var data =  [
  {
    SKU: 'CS4',
    Name: 'Dell Laptop Inspiron 41',
    Quantity: 1,
    ItemPrice: 121
  }
];

var total_reviews = 5;

for (var i = 1; i <= total_reviews; i++) {
  // This doesn't work because you are trying to push it to an Array.
  // Object.assign(data.Reviews, { "ID": data.from.other.sites.ID, "Name": data.from.other.sites.NAME });
  
  // First make sure that the array is initialized.
  data[0].Reviews = data[0].Reviews || [];
  
  // Then add the object to your array.
  data[0].Reviews.push({
    "ID": "data.from.other.sites.ID",
    "NAME": "data.from.other.sites.NAME"
  });
}
```

Comment: @cjatstackoverflow => The only error that is there is because of the "made-up object structure with all the periods" that he referenced that I just re-used. Let me make an edit really quick and then it shouldn't show any errors anymore.

Edit completed. It no longer errors.

Comment: @th3n3wguy Yeah, I'm just messing with you. :D Peace out.

Comment: @cjatstackoverflow => Troll successful (by you, that is), but don't be too proud of yourself. I am fairly-gullable.

Answer (score 1):

```
data[0].Reviews = []

for (i=1; i<=total_reviews; i++) {

     data[0].Reviews.push({ "ID": data.from.other.sites.ID, "Name": data.from.other.sites.NAME })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you moving in the correct direction:

```
if(!data.Reviews){
  data.Reviews = []
}
review = {"ID": "someId", "Name": "someName"}
data.Reviews.push(review)
```

Comment: Correct, you would put this within your loop and it will populate your Reviews object with each review in the loop.  Just replace the "someId" and "someName" with the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your data object isn't an plain object.
It's an array.

So if you want to add new Reviews into an element of that array, find the element by it's key (unique identifier) and push the new Review into the elements 'Reviews' property.

```
const index = data.indexOf(element => element.id === id);
if (index !== -1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < total_reviews; i++) {
        data[index]['Reviews'].push({ "ID": data.from.other.sites.ID, "Name": data.from.other.sites.NAME };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```js
var data =  {
        SKU: 'CS4',
        Name: 'Dell Laptop Inspiron 41',
        Quantity: 1,
        ItemPrice: 121,
        "Reviews" : [
        {
            "ID": 2551,
            "Name": 'john',
        },
        {
            "ID": 255551,
            "Name": 'j5ohn',

        }]
    };
    var total_reviews = 5;
    for (i=1; i<=total_reviews; i++) {

         data.Reviews.push({ "ID": 'id_'+i, "Name": 'name_'+i })

    }
    console.log(data.Reviews);
```